# Google Apps Script refresh sheet while function is running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some script in my Google Sheets/ It can take a lot of time to finish all this script (up to 5 minutes I think). And I want to show some message that user should just wait a little. So I have some code like:

```
function test(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  sheet.clear();
  cell.setValue('WAIT!!!!');
  DATA = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  // And some action that takes a lot of time ....
  cell.setValue('DONE!!!!');
```

But it doesn't show "WAIT" it only shows me "DONE" when everything is ok. It can only show me "WAIT" if there was any error and function crashed. It looks like I need to refresh it somehow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call the [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush())method after you set the cell value to wait.

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //Applies all pending Spreadsheet changes.
```

Comment: That won't help. It shows nothing because the script runs on server side and returns nothing until it finishes.

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is specifically made update the sheet while the script is still running and doesn't need anything returned. I called it before an infinite loop just to check and it still updated the sheet.

Comment: hmmm, just tested and it works indeed, sorry, I'm pretty sure it wasn't working on previous version of spreadsheets .. my bad, I should have checked ! upvote to compensate ;).

Comment: Does this work if im going through a loop, setting values for each row, but I want to show each row being added as i go through my loop? I've tried adding it after my setValues(data) but don't see anything. Basically I have about 50+ rows each time i run my function and I want to see each row being added while the script runs. Thanks in advance!